# Which of <= and < comparison operators use less gas in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, gas, security, optimization

```
if(num <= 10) revert();
```

And

```
if(num < 11) revert();
```

Which of these statements consume less gas?

If we could save gas, we need not use less than/greater than equal to. We can just use less than or greater than along with the next integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LE (lower or equal) opcode does not exist on EVM, the operation is accomplished as a combination of existing opcodes. The specific combination will depend on the compiler version, optimizer, and code context, etc.

In that specific example the opcode for

```
    if(num <= 10) revert();
```

is

```
      PUSH A                push 10
      DUP2                  num
      GT                    num>10
      PUSH [tag] 15         tag if GT is true
      JUMPI                 jump if true
```

and for

```
    if(num < 11) revert();
```

is

```
      PUSH A                push 11
      DUP2                  num
      LT                    num<11
      ISZERO                negate LT
      PUSH [tag] 15         tag
      JUMPI                 jump if true
```

So, using `<` option will be 3 gas more expensive than using the `<=` due to the extra ISZERO opcode. But, in some cases like

```
     return num <= 10;
```

```
      PUSH A            10
      DUP3              num
      GT                num > 10
      ISZERO            negate GT
```

```
     return num < 11;
```

```
      PUSH B            11
      DUP3              num
      LT                num < 11
```

Using `<=` will be the one costing 3 more gas.

In conclusion, it depends on the code context which one is more efficient but, the 3-gas difference is negligible so, could consider using either.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not so straightforward. EVM has only the [**`LT`**](https://www.evm.codes/) opcode, so the two statements for operators `<` and `<=` are **different**. Therefore, the compiler should represent the `<=` behavior with another flow. I thought the compiler would output the `EQ` opcode additionally. But instead, a completely other bytecode is generated for the methods (`num <= 10` / `num < 10`):

```typescript
contract Foo {
    function bar (uint num) external  {
        if (num <= 10) {
            revert();
        }
    }
}
```

- [evm.codes **<**](https://bit.ly/3pnvTYZ)
- [evm.codes **<=**](https://bit.ly/3NEQotr)

Click `run` and compare the bytecode in some diff tools, the difference will be significant.

I executed `bar` method tests locally (`solidity 0.8.12`) for the versions of the contract with:

- `num < 10`
- `num <= 10`
- `num < 11` (just for ref)

and got interesting results:

| Values and Operator | Gas |
| --- | --- |
| 8 < 10 | 21425 |
| 8 <= 10 | 21422 |
| 10 <= 10 | 21422 |
| 8 < 11 | 21425 |
| 10 < 11 | 21425 |
| 20 < 10 | 21431 |
| 20 <= 10 | 21428 |
| 20 < 11 | 21431 |

`<=` consumed less gas in that contract example. Remember, that the optimizer could work differently for your codebase.